Is it true that if $g(x)g(1-x)=1$, then $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{f(1-x)}$ for some $f$?
The statement is simple: we have a  function $g:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}^+$ that verifies the functional equation $$g(x)\cdot g(1-x)=1$$ for every $x$ in its domain, and we wish to find another function $f$ such that $g(x)=f(x)/f(1-x)$. I wonder if this function always exists, and if not, what conditions are required for its existence.
After some thinking, I could't come up with a counterexample, but didn't manage to write a proof neither.
Notice that the opposite implication is trivial, and this together with the lack of "easy" counterexamples lead me to think the two conditions are indeed equivalent.
So, the question is: is this true without restrictions?(yes as @BrianMohering pointed out in the comments)
What about continuous functions $g$ and $f$? Does the result still hold?

Easy counterexample: What if $g(1/2)=-1$?  (You may want to change the problem to remove this "trivial" counterexample)

With that fix, what if you simply define $f(x) = g(x)$ for $x\geq 1/2$? (This is what my initial comment meant.  $f(x)$ can almost be arbitrarily defined.  It's not well-defined by the problem)

Interesting question... Maybe to be solved by restricting the domain to $(0,1)$ and the range to $\mathbb{R^+}$...

I think @BrianMoehring is suggesting that you define $f(x)=g(x)$ for $x\ge\frac12$, and $f(x)=1$ for $x<\frac12$.

By any chance do you mean for $g$ and $f$ to be meromorphic functions? Then the question is less trivial...

@paulgarrett I was working with continuous real-valued functions when I encountered this, so a continuous answer would suit best

@TonyK I see. This works indeed. Maybe would it be interesting to look for continuous functions? Imma edit the question

Let $u:[\frac12,\infty)\to\Bbb R^+$ be any strictly positive function satisfying $u(\frac12)=1$. Then we can define
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}u(x)&\text{ if }x\ge\tfrac12\\
g(x)u(1-x)&\text{ if } x<\tfrac12\end{cases}$$
and this satisfies $g(x)=f(x)/f(1-x)$ for all $x\in\text{dom } g$.
Moreover, $f$ is continuous if both $g$ and $u$ are continuous.

Very clever solution, thank you very much
